# Confused about the: foreach looped value I receive

Tags: php

HI have create a foreach loop and I get a value but I can not understand why I get the value I get.
Can anyone explain the reason why i get 321 as the output rather than the 123 ?

```
<?php
    $numbers = array(1,2,3,4);
    $total = count($numbers);
    $output = "";
    $i = 0;

    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        if ($i < $total) {
            $output = $number . $output;
        }
    }

    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: what's the point of the `$i < $total` check?

Comment: On another topic, you should probably be incrementing `$i` after the if block... although the if block is also redundant as foreach will only loop over the available values of `$numbers`

Comment: Granted, this entire foreach is redundant thanks to the [`implode`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) command.

Comment: Also, not directly related to the question, but I'd do `$i++;`, just to make it a little more compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$output = $number . $output;` is appending the new number at the start of output, rather than at the end.

`$output = $output . $number;` should give you what you expect.

As Phil Perry suggests,`$output .= $number;` will also work, and is a bit shorter.

Comment: Even better, `$output .= $number;`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are appending the strings in the wrong order...

```
$output = $number . $output;
```

instead do

```
$output = $output . $number;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're prepending the current number to your output instead of appending.

`$output = $output . $number;`

Would give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the solution.
but shouldn't your code for $total be:

$total = count($numbers) -1;

now you have:

$total = count($numbers);

arrays start counting at 0 and the count option starts at 1. 
because your $i allready is 0 it outputs 1 time to often. (correct me if im wrong)